# Wordpress wp_list_pages list siblings if no children?

Tags: wordpress

Struggling trying to nail the wp_list_pages proper query.

I basically want to put a sidebar function showing a returned list of wp_list_pages depending on the structure of the content. If the page the user is on has children, I want the children displayed there.

If the page has no children, I want siblings displayed there.

I know this must be pretty straight forward but I'm struggling with it. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Got some help from someone else, this worked pretty good!

```html
global $post;
 if (is_page( )) {
  $page = $post->ID;
  $children=wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&depth=1' );
  if ($children) {
   $output = wp_list_pages ('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=' . $post->post_title . ' Subpages&echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&depth=1');
  }
  else {
   $page = $post->post_parent;
   $output = wp_list_pages ('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=Similar Pages&echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&depth=1');
  }
 }
 return $output;
```